# What would be the true position (top, left) be of a rotated element if its height is increased by some value

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is rotated at a certain angle. If I am to increase the height of the div by some value. How can I get or calculate the true top and left value of the current div and the true top and left value of the div after the height is increased at the same time. I want to calculate these values to preserve the original true bottom right position after the height is increased

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a54h2yLs/) describes the problem that I am trying to solve

```
const increaseHeight = function(div){
/*
calculate the true top and left of the div
calculate the true top and left of the div after the height is increased
calculate the difference that needs to be applied such that when the height changes the original true bottom right position remains the same after the height is increased
  */    
 }
```

Note that I want to solve this only using javascript and no extra css applied

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to retrieve properties of a transformed element:

```
var x = document.getElementById("app");
console.log(x.getBoundingClientRect());
```

Your fiddle should log:

> DOMRect {x: 17.10739517211914, y: 47.10739517211914, width: 265.78521728515625, height: 265.78521728515625, top: 47.10739517211914, …}

Comment: This gives the position of the boundingclientrect which is not the actual position of the rotated div

Comment: Actually, if you call the function without transforming your div, it returns original values (i.e. width 200px)